# Dual booting Kali linux and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Kali Linux is my main os(because it didn't work when I tried dual booting with Ubuntu) so as i'm trying to install Ubuntu when I can select weather to dual boot or remove Kali I choose dual. Then I got the error `The test of the file system with type ext4 in partition #1 of SCSI1(0,0,0)(sda) found uncorrected errors. If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct these errors, the partition will be used as is`. I select continue and it gives the error: `An error occured while writing the changes to the storage devices. The resize operation has been aborted.` 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was install Ubuntu and go to the custom install then only used up half of my hard drive for Ubuntu then went into Kali Linux and selected install for largest continuing free space and it worked I know this question is kind of old but the answer above didn't help out what so ever(don't know how it ever got an up vote?)

Answer (score 1):

You MUST `go back to the partitioning menu and correct these errors`, before you have a chance of resizing anything. You MUST.

Also, Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, hair loss, failure and frustration. Doomed, I say!